# How can I implement If-ElseIf-Else condition in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

In NiFi,
I have a JSON data coming in, and I am using SplitJson and EvaluateJson to store the required components of the Json data in my own variable.

How can I implement an if-elseif-else condition on the Json data value?

For example, if attributeA==0, relationship = pass, else fail, and so on.

Answer (score 9):

You will use the [`RouteOnAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/) processor with dynamic properties that evaluate the [NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) against the provided attributes. Here are sections of the documentation on [boolean operations](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#boolean) and [evaluating multiple attributes](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#multi).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to implement an If-ElseIf-Else condition, you can do it like this:

```
${
LogData:jsonPath('$.email'):equals('DEV'):not():ifElse(
    ${LogData:jsonPath('$.email'):equals('QA'):ifElse(
        'aa',
        'bb'
    )},
    'cc'
)}
```

Note that using this approach you can create as nested conditions as you need, but if you need to do some routing it's better to use the [RouteOnAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/index.html) processor as @andy said.

Comment: Thank you for answering the actual question, even though the first answer was better for what the OP needed.  This is helpful for those of us with different, but related problems.